# Spring boot (3.2.1) Resource server authentication with Spring boot (2.2.4) auth server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-resource-server

This is the code snippet of my authorization server which is running on spring boot 2.2.4 and running on port 7220. I can get the access token by calling this API call http://localhost:7220/oauth/token

```
<?xml>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <description>my authentication Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MyAuthenticationServiceApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WellnessAuthenticationServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final GeneralUtil generalUtil;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Value("${user.oauth.client}")
    private String client;

    @Value("${user.oauth.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter() {
            @Override
            public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken, OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication) {
                userRepository.findById(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) oAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                        .ifPresent(user ->
                                ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) oAuth2AccessToken).setAdditionalInformation(Map.of(
                                        "firstName", user.getFirstName(),
                                        "lastName", user.getLastName(),
                                        "email", user.getEmail(),
                                        "phoneNumber", user.getPhoneNumber(),
                                        "configured", user.isConfigured())));

                return super.enhance(oAuth2AccessToken, oAuth2Authentication);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public WebResponseExceptionTranslator<OAuth2Exception> loggingExceptionTranslator() {
        return new DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator() {
            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {
                return super.translate(e);
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(client).secret(passwordEncoder.encode(secret)).authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").scopes("openid").accessTokenValiditySeconds(60000).refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        endpoints.exceptionTranslator(loggingExceptionTranslator());
        endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        endpoints.reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }

}
```

Below is the code snippet of my resource server which is running on spring boot 3.2.1.

```
<?xml>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-dashboard-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-dashboard-gateway</name>
    <description>my dashboard Gateway</description>m
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <!--version>1.18.30</version-->
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


application.properties
spring.application.name=my-dashboard-gateway
server.port=7240
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:7220
```

This is the endpoint that i am trying to access which is defined my-dashboard-gateway(resource server).

```
@GetMapping("/companies")
public ResponseEntity<String> get() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Hello this is my company");
}
```

This is the exception occurred in on my resource server.

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meGpZ.png)

This is the exception occurred in authentication server.

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sbo8.png)

Problem is Resource server is running on a new version and auth server is running on a old version.How do we validate the token coming to the resource server. what sort of configurations we need. Is there anything we have to do with following two end points

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.key-set-uri
```